# Voting doesn't work on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, mobile-web

If I try to vote on the mobile site, all I get is the message that an error occurred. I've tried clearing my network settings, and logging out an in. Nothing fixes it. The only way to fix it is to use the full site. Who broke it this time?

For reference, I'm using an iPhone 4S with iOS 6.1.3 running Chrome 27.0.1453.10 (WebKit 536.26):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/27.0.1453.10 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot for the illiterate]

Comment: I can report the same problem since yesterday on the android standard browser (galaxy s3). Visiting the desktop site from a mobile browser doesnt show the problem however

Comment: Tried to up vote this but can't. From chrome on nexus 4

Comment: @user000001 Its a conspiracy!  Or use the "full site" link at the bottom to temporarily change to desktop mode

Comment: @Richard Thanx it worked :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed in release 2013.7.17.854 (meta release 2013.7.17.1226)

Comment: I voted this from my mobile!

Comment: What went wrong, if I might ask? :)

Comment: short explanation: mobile view wasn't up to date...

Comment: I assume the long explanation comes with a ream of source code for context

Comment: It was my fault.  There is a hidden input in the voting div which the voting js uses to submit the post id with the vote.  I added a name attribute to it and changed the js to look for that name and forgot to add the same attribute in the mobile view, and....whammo! no voting for you!  Thanks to @m0sa for fixing it.